# Avro GenericData toString writing bytes array in ISO 8859 charset?

Tags: java, json, avro

A `GenericRecord` can be converted to a Json using `toString()`. In the class `GenericData` the implementation of that `toString()` will convert a value of type `bytes` (a bytes array) to a string in the charset `ISO_8859_1`.

see: [Apache Avro Github](https://github.com/apache/avro/blob/ec4ca5d56e55480dd3970181c20c3a5e6e9f2303/lang/java/avro/src/main/java/org/apache/avro/generic/GenericData.java#L747C6-L747C77)

I expected that the bytes array would be converted to an UTF-8 encoded json text. After all json text is a sequence of unicode code points.
Is this a bug or is there a reason for this behavior?

Avro version: 1.11.3